# Get interval from List - Java

Tags: java, list

If possible get interval from `List<Object>`

The intervals are after **two** elements
Live example:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(a);
myList.add(b);
myList.add(c);
myList.add(d);
myList.add(e);
```

GET 1st interval (element on 0 and 1):

> a, b

Get 2nd interval (element on 2 and 3):

> c, d

Get 3rd interval (element on 4 and 5-not exist)

> e

Is there any easy way?

Sure i can make own code. But is there simple way?

Thank you.

Comment: I can think of a single method that is like maybe 4-5 lines. But I hope you could write that yourself also.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: Hint: ArrayList should have a get method which takes an int to specify a element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the obvious answer:

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
ls.add("Hello");
ls.add("World");
ls.add("Pair");
ls.add("Words");
ls.add("Another");
ls.add("Pair");

for (int i = 0; i < (ls.size() - 1); i = i + 2) {
    System.out.println("First: " + ls.get(i) +
                       ", Second: " + ls.get(i + 1));
}
```

Output:

```
First: Hello, Second: World
First: Pair, Second: Words
First: Another, Second: Pair
```

Another solution might be efficient if you needed groups of many items instead of just two (produces same output):

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
ls.add("Hello");
ls.add("World");
ls.add("Pair");
ls.add("Words");
ls.add("Another");
ls.add("Pair");

for (int i = 0; i < (ls.size() - 1); i = i + 2) {
    ListIterator<String> iter = ls.listIterator(i);
    System.out.println("First: " + iter.next() +
                       ", Second: " + iter.next());
}
```

But generally, if you want to do that, you'd make a container to hold your pairs and just iterate the list of pairs the usual way (produces the same output).

```
class Pair<T,U> {
    T _1;
    U _2;
    public Pair(T t, U u) { _1 = t; _2 = u; }
}

List<Pair<String,String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
pairs.add(new Pair<>("Hello", "World"));
pairs.add(new Pair<>("Pair", "Words"));
pairs.add(new Pair<>("Another", "Pair"));

for (Pair<String,String> pair : pairs) {
    System.out.println("First: " + pair._1 +
                       ", Second: " + pair._2);
}
```

If you want to get all functional/immutable, you can use [Paguro](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/Paguro) with Java 8 streams (produces same output):

```
List<Tuple2<String,String>> ls =
        vec(tup("Hello", "World"),
            tup("Pair", "Words"),
            tup("Another", "Pair"));

ls.forEach(pair -> System.out.println("First: " + pair._1() +
                                      " Second: " + pair._2()));
```

In conclusion: no.  There's no "partition" method on List.  There are some partitioning methods on SortedSet though (`headSet(to)`, `tailSet(from)`, and `subSet(from, to)`), so if you don't have duplicates in your list, and your items are ordered, you could play with that.

Comment: How is this "simple" or what OP asked? You explicitly made a List of Tuples

Comment: He didn't ask for (a,b), (b,c)...  He asked for (a,b), (c,d)...  These are better entered into the list as tuples.  He said he knew the `ls.get(i);`  `ls.get(i+1);` `i = i + 2;` answer already.

Comment: Sure, but this method requires an extra class (or library) and needing the extra storage for an even number of elements.

Comment: OK, I added a third version (put it first) that does exactly what was asked for.  For bigger clumps, it would probably even be very efficient.

Comment: Your added way still only works with an even number of elements

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind adding a library to your project, try using Google Guava:

```
List< String > list = Arrays.asList( a, b, c, d, e );
List< List< String > > sets = Lists.partition( list, 2 );

sets.forEach( ( set ) -> System.out.println( set ) );
```

This way, you can just change the size of the partitions if you later need to group a different number of values.

Output:

```
[a, b]
[c, d]
[e]
```

Answer (score 2):

And if you *don't* want to use a library

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    int intervalSize = 2;
    int maxIntervals = (int) Math.ceil(myList.size() / (1.0*intervalSize));
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxIntervals; i++) {
        System.out.println(getInterval(myList, i, intervalSize));
    }
    // [1, 2]
    // [3, 4]
    // [5]
}

private static List getInterval(List lst, int interval, int intervalSize) {
    if (intervalSize < 0 || interval <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    int intervalStart = -intervalSize;

    while (intervalStart < lst.size() && interval > 0) {
        intervalStart += intervalSize;
        interval--;
    }

    int intervalEnd = Math.min(intervalStart + intervalSize, lst.size());
    return lst.subList(intervalStart, intervalEnd);
}
```